# Do not nest generic types in member signatures

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have acquired an extension class which implements the following members with signatures that are violating the CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures rule.

The code to which the warning refers is included below.

How should I refactor the code to resolve the CA1006 warning?

Please keep in mind that I am not very familiar with expression trees, although I do have a pretty good grasp of anonymous methods, delegates, and lambdas.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static DataServiceQuery<TElement> Expand<TElement, TPropType>(this DataServiceQuery<TElement> source, Expression<Func<TElement, TPropType>> propertySelector) 
    {
        string includeString = BuildString(propertySelector);
        return source.Expand(includeString);
    }

    private static string BuildString(Expression propertySelector)
    {
        switch (propertySelector.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Lambda:
                LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)propertySelector;
                return BuildString(lambdaExpression.Body);

            case ExpressionType.Quote:
                UnaryExpression unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)propertySelector;
                return BuildString(unaryExpression.Operand);

            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:

                MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector;
                MemberInfo propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member;

                if (memberExpression.Expression is ParameterExpression)
                {
                    return propertyInfo.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    // we've got a nested property (e.g. MyType.SomeProperty.SomeNestedProperty)
                    return BuildString(memberExpression.Expression) + "/" + propertyInfo.Name;
                }

            case ExpressionType.Call:
                MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)propertySelector;
                if (IsSubInclude(methodCallExpression.Method)) // check that it's a SubInclude call
                {
                    // argument 0 is the expression to which the SubInclude is applied (this could be member access or another SubInclude)
                    // argument 1 is the expression to apply to get the included property
                    // Pass both to BuildString to get the full expression
                    return BuildString(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]) + "/" +
                           BuildString(methodCallExpression.Arguments[1]);
                }
                // else drop out and throw
                break;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression or an SubInclude call: " + propertySelector.ToString());

    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo[] SubIncludeMethods;
    static MyExtensions()
    {
        Type type = typeof(MyExtensions);
        SubIncludeMethods = type.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == "SubExpand").ToArray();
    }

    private static bool IsSubInclude(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (methodInfo.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            if (!methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
            {
                methodInfo = methodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
            }
        }
        return SubIncludeMethods.Contains(methodInfo);
    }

    public static TPropType SubExpand<TSource, TPropType>(this Collection<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TPropType>> propertySelector)
        where TSource : class
        where TPropType : class
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method is only intended for use with DataServiceQueryExtensions.Expand to generate expressions trees"); // no actually using this - just want the expression! 
    }

    public static TPropType SubExpand<TSource, TPropType>(this TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TPropType>> propertySelector)
        where TSource : class
        where TPropType : class
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This method is only intended for use with DataServiceQueryExtensions.Expand to generate expressions trees"); // no actually using this - just want the expression! 
    }
```

Comment: can you give an example of this code being used? It's quite complex and a little tricky to see where the fault is

Comment: Is that referring to the propertySelector parameter of the public method? The warning is about making an interface to a method usable - but with an Expression, I don't see how it could be refactored unless you wrap the expression parameter in a class which provides it as a a return from a property or method call.

Comment: DiskJunky, thanks for your interest in helping to resolve this issue.  Essentially, the code is being used to build lambda expressions as in the following. var scenarioGroups = from scenarioGroup in ctx.ScenarioGroups.Expand(scenarioGroup => scenarioGroup.Scenarios.SubExpand(sc => sc.XYLines.SubExpand(xy => xy.Points))) where ...

Comment: And yes, Jay, it does.  Furthermore, I think you're right in your assessment.  However, I've been asked to explore possible alternatives to nesting rather than suppression of the warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning is a general warning supposed to help you design a better and simpler public interface. In this case you get a warning about having a `Expression<Func<TElement, TPropType>>` parameter in your method. However, for this method there is no point in simplifying the type and instead you should suppress the warning using an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) or completely remove the rule from your ruleset.

---

A silly example where you probably should consider following the advice of the rule is a method like this:

```
public void F(Dictionary<String, List<Tuple<String, Int32>>> dictionary);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin.  I believe you are correct.  It has become obvious that it is pointless to try and simplify the type.  I'll just have to suppress it instead.

Comment: After keeping this warning for a while I suppressed it as it was causing too much noise. Found out that 99% of the time the usage of a nested generic type with a "depth" of 1 (T<T<>>)was legitimate. Waiting for the rule to be refined to trigger only for a starting depth of 2 (T<T<T<>>>) which would make much more sense ;)