# Why is ReadOnlyCollection<ReadOnlyCollection<T>> bad according to FxCop and what is the alternative when producing an immutable 2 dimensional object?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, fxcop, readonly-collection

I am modifying all my code to conform to FxCop and this has meant ditching a lot of arrays, lists in favour of ReadOnlyCollection and I agree with this advice. However, when producing a

```
ReadOnlyCollection<ReadOnlyCollection<T>>
```

to replace a two-dimensional array or

```
List<List<T>> I now get the
```

[CA1006: Do not nest generic types in member signatures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182144.aspx)

complaint. Firstly, although it looks unwieldy it doesn't appear to be very complex or difficult to understand as it is essentially an immutable `List<List<T>>`, which I imagine are extremely common given the drawbacks of arrays.
Secondly, I cannot think of an alternative that stores two dimensional data and is immutable unless I am to create a new type especially for this.

What is best practice here please. Could it be that this FxCop rule doesn't really apply here and should be suppressed?

Many thanks.

Comment: Non-opinion based portion of your question is already answered on the site ([CA1006](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945199/do-not-nest-generic-types-in-member-signatures)). You may also consider new immutable types as alternative - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210428/are-immutable-arrays-possible-in-net which would be better choice (as ReadonlyCollection are actually not immutable - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438988/readonlycollection-are-the-objects-immutable).

Comment: Does the user of your type really expect to use it as a collection-of-collections, or do they expect to use it as a collection that requires two indices? The latter seems more likely; consider making your own collection type that uses a "nested" collection like this as an implementation detail, not as the public interface.

Comment: @EricLippert The user wants a collection with two indices. The syntax of an array is much simpler than that of a collection of collections and given that it cannot be changed in any way I can't see any advantages of the latter. I don't think an array like this exists, which surprises me as I would of thought that lots of other developers would have travelled down the same path that I am on of a) Passing immutable arrays to eliminate the unexpected. b) Being thread safe c) Reducing change and therefore complexity d) Adhering to FxCop. I think my best option is ImmutableList<ImmutableList<T>>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comments on this post seem to apply here as well:

> The warning is a general warning supposed to help you design a better
>   and simpler public interface. In this case you get a warning about
>   having a Expression> parameter in your
>   method. However, for this method there is no point in simplifying the
>   type and instead you should suppress the warning using an attribute or
>   completely remove the rule from your ruleset.
>
> A silly example where you probably should consider following the
>   advice of the rule is a method like this:
>
> public void F(`Dictionary<String, List<Tuple<<String, Int32>>>`
>   dictionary);

Martin Liversage's answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945331/1775528

Comment: Please vote/flag to close as duplicate if you believe exact answer to another question is enough. Posting whole answer (even with attribution) is not a good practice.

Comment: if you think thats the answer then mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for that. Is         ReadOnlyCollection<ReadOnlyCollection<T>> a common construct because I haven't found many examples of it being used but I would have thought that it would be very common when immutability is desired.

Comment: @Pedruski i think thats not common... jagged arrays are more common... `T[][]`

Comment: I read Martin's answer before posting but thought that my question was different as it was with regards to ReadOnlyCollection<ReadOnlyCollection<T>> which I still think must be a very common signature but I found very little about on stackoverflow or the internet generally. I also read about the new immutable collections but didn't think they applied as they would also be ImmutableList<ImmutableList<T>> which would receive the same error in FxCop. Thanks for your input. I understand if you wish to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: For the record I will continue to use ReadOnlyCollection<ReadOnlyCollection<T>> and suppress the warnings in FxCop.